# Is it possible to access the audio output stream after it has been mixed with android ndk?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, oboe

I am trying to modify audio output streams from for example a media player app before it is send to the loudspeakers on android. Is that theoretically possible somehow?

Comment: It depends if you're talking about simple volume controls, or something else entirely. There might be a way to alter general volume for other sounds, but otherwise getting the physical stream would be too intrusive for other apps, so I wouldn't think that would be possible.

Comment: Volumes would be the one thing, but I also intended to introduce some kind of delays. Accessing the output volumes could be enough though, if it is possible to mute the other apps audio output while still being able to capture its unmuted audio via the newly introduced Playback capture in Android 10.
Would you share your secrets about altering general volumes for other sounds?

Comment: I stand corrected, this might not be possible. I was just thinking it might, considering how google maps pauses/turns down the volume when giving directions. https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-adjust-the-volume-of-different-apps-independently-on-Android

Comment: If you want that level of manipulation, perhaps it's better to create your own media player? Or else find one that can work as an API.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to access the audio frames directly, however, you can use the subclasses of [`AudioEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect), such as `Equalizer` and `DynamicsProcessing` to add effects to the global output mix. You will need to assign these effects to session id `0`.

Comment: But as far as I can see there is no possibility to introduce your own transfer functions including delay, right? And doing this in stereo.

Comment: That's correct. You are limited to configuring the system provided effects. You cannot supply your own.